# Displaying laravel error messages on redirect

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a form which i am hoping to use to insert some data to mysql. I have setup the validator like this

```
public function insert_post(){
        $rules = array(
            'model' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'engine' => 'required'
                 );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {

            // get the error messages from the validator
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($messages);
            echo '</pre>';
            return Redirect::to('create-posts')
                ->withErrors($validator);
        }
        else {
            $i = new Text;
            $i->model = request('model');
            $i->country = request('country');
            $i->engine = request('engine');
            $i->save();
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

My `create-posts` route looks like this.

```
 public function create_post(){
        return view('create-posts');
    }
```

However, its not displaying the error since i think i am loading a fresh `create-posts` and the validator messages are lost.

view code

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Model</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="model" placeholder="Model">
           @if ($errors->has('model')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('model') }}</p> @endif
           </div>
        </div>
```

Is that what's the cause?.

Comment: laravel version 5.4

Comment: Are you accessing the `$errors` variable in the views? Can you post the view code?

Comment: Would prefer to use `return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);`, try to print the `$errors` variable on the view to see if is not set :)

Comment: @Troyer `return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to return to the last view, you can use:

`return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);`

Instead of `return Redirect::to('create-posts')->withErrors($validator);`.